# Simple C# Beginner Question

Tags: c#, methods

I am trying to make a simple calculator. I am getting blue line under my numbers with the error  "Method Name Expected"

I was hopeing you guys could help me out with my simple question from a noob.

```
finalCmb = .25(1.3(txtAtt.Text+txtStr.Text)+txtDef.Text+txtHp.Text+(.5(txtPray.Text))+(.5(txtSum.Text)));
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by saying `= .25(...)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You have to manually place multiplication operators. There is no bracket multiplication.

   `25(1.3(te...` should be `25 * (1.3 * (te...`
2. Converting strings to numbers would be a good idea.

   `txtStr.Text` to `Double.Parse(txtStr.Text)`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much this helped me but i also had to change them to fractions. Such as 1.3 -> 13/10.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the asterisk symbol for multiplication.

Comment: -1. Only half the problem (the other is trying to do math with text).

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong.  The compiler thinks that you are trying to call a method due to the opening parentheses when you do this

```
.25(1.3 ...
```

I'm not sure what you are actually trying to accomplish with that, but it doesn't make sense.  I would suggest spending some more time learning the basics.

Comment: -1. Saying "you have a problem" isn't helpful. See @Tim Cooper's answer for one that actually helps.

Comment: @Ken White: When did I say "you have a problem"?  I don't see that quoted text in my post, but anyway... you are correct in saying Tim's answer is better.  I didn't realize right away what the OP was actually trying to accomplish and left the page.  However, I would argue that giving the answer here will not help very much either (not that it's a bad thing to do) because the OP obviously doesn't understand the fundamentals of the language at all.  They need to study up before starting any type of project.

Answer (score -1):

```
finalCmb = .25 * (1.3 * ((double)txtAtt.Text + (double)txtStr.Text)+(double)txtDef.Text+ (double)txtHp.Text+ (.5 * ((double)txtPray.Text)) + (.5 * ((double)txtSum.Text)));
```

Comment: Yay for the ability to copy and paste a section of text. Is this supposed to be some sort of answer?

Comment: He asked a very simple question.  He said he got a blue line, I got rid of the blue line and casted this textboxes.  Don't be a jerk about it.  Also, you can type cast as long as there is a number in the box.  You don't know if he has validation or not.  I did not copy and paste anything.  Pretentious.

Comment: To be fair I posted that comment when it was an unformatted garbled mess.